# Regular surface with constant mean curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, quadratic-forms

I've been looking for an interesting problem, that is to find a quadratic form $F:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}$, given by $F(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2 + dxy + exz + fyz + h$ such that image inverse of $F$ by $0$ is a regular surface with constant mean curvature. In this context, $0$ is regular value of $F$.

I appreciate any attempt to help

Comment: In Cartesian polynomial form it could involve hyper elliptic functions.

Comment: You'll only get constant mean curvature in the case $F=c$ is a sphere. (When the level set is compact, this follows from Alexandrov's Theorem.  In the case of a hyperboloids, you can take a standard form and just check.)